# React-native transformer taking too much time

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native with scala.js. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/chandu0101/569ae43d1d38550413115e5bea4ea851) of my index.ios.js and package.json files.

Transform statistics :

```
[12:20:44 PM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true (700ms) 
[12:20:58 PM] <START> find dependencies 
[12:20:59 PM] <END>   find dependencies (443ms) 
[12:20:59 PM] <START> transform transforming [========================================] 100% 524/525
[12:21:05 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true transforming [========================================] 100% 525/525 [12:21:24 PM] <END>   transform (25137ms) 
[12:21:24 PM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true (19293ms)
```

It took almost ~20 seconds to transform and for every small change I make I have to wait the same amount of time.

How can I improve this time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution for this problem : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6830

**Edit :**

Root cause for the issue is babel.transform didn't like my scala.js output, to fix this modify transform.js file packager.

```
const result = babel.transform(src, babelConfig);
                           |
                          To
 const result = filename.indexOf("index.ios.js") > -1 ? {code : src}  : babel.transform(src, babelConfig);
```

Comment: @invariant I was one of those who downvoted, because after 4.4k rep you should know how to answer questions on SO, and that posting link-only answers is not acceptable (It's even one of the standard deletion reasons in the Low Quality Review Queue). Now that you edited your post I removed my downvote. Please keep what Floern said in mind when writing your next answer.

Comment: @Adriaan thanks for reply , it doesnt matter of how much rep we have we always make mistakes! i wouldn't down vote if  i came across this situation when link is actually makes sense( different people different thought process yeah ..).